# MySQL next entry after certain condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table with history of transfers for codes.
These can travel between different locations like (X,Y,Z,etc.)

This is an example table of transfers for code: 102263

```
mysql> SELECT datetime, code, location FROM table WHERE code LIKE '102263'

+-----datetime-----+----code----+----location----+
|  5.1.2017 12:54  |  102263    |       X        |  
|  2.2.2017 8:42   |  102263    |       Y        | <--- first transfer from X to Y
|  2.3.2017 12:04  |  102263    |       Z        |
|  6.3.2017 13:34  |  102263    |       Y        |
|  7.3.2017 7:57   |  102263    |       Z        |
|  7.3.2017 18:37  |  102263    |       Y        |
|  9.3.2017 17:47  |  102263    |       Z        |
|  13.3.2017 7:56  |  102263    |       Y        |
|  21.3.2017 11:44 |  102263    |       Z        | 
|  22.3.2017 20:28 |  102263    |       Y        |
|  24.3.2017 13:07 |  102263    |       X        | 
|  25.3.2017 14:01 |  102263    |       Y        | <--- second transfer from X to Y
|  26.3.2017 8:14  |  102263    |       Z        |
|  27.3.2017 9:52  |  102263    |       Y        |
|  3.4.2017 10:02  |  102263    |       X        | <--- beginning of third transfer
+------------------+------------+----------------+
```

I need to select data between specific two locations(X and Y), but only the first transfer from X to Y then the next transfer between X and Y, etc. ignoring all the entries between (Z and Y). 
So the result should be:

```
+-----datetime-----+----code----+----location----+
| 5.1.2017 12:54   |   102263   |        X       |
| 2.2.2017 8:42    |   102263   |        Y       | <--- first transfer from X to Y
| 24.3.2017 13:07  |   102263   |        X       |
| 25.3.2017 14:01  |   102263   |        Y       | <--- second transfer from X to Y
| 3.4.2017 10:02   |   102263   |        X       | <--- beginning of third transfer
+------------------+------------+----------------+
```

I tried to limit to locations to X and Y, but I also need to skip the Y dates that are not directly after X

```
mysql> SELECT datetime, code, location FROM table WHERE code LIKE '102263' AND (location LIKE 'X' OR location LIKE 'Y')

+-----datetime-----+----code----+----location----+
|  5.1.2017 12:54  |  102263    |       X        |  
|  2.2.2017 8:42   |  102263    |       Y        | <--- first transfer from X to Y
|  6.3.2017 13:34  |  102263    |       Y        | <--- skip
|  7.3.2017 18:37  |  102263    |       Y        | <--- skip
|  13.3.2017 7:56  |  102263    |       Y        | <--- skip
|  22.3.2017 20:28 |  102263    |       Y        | <--- skip
|  24.3.2017 13:07 |  102263    |       X        | 
|  25.3.2017 14:01 |  102263    |       Y        | <--- second transfer from X to Y
|  27.3.2017 9:52  |  102263    |       Y        | <--- skip
|  3.4.2017 10:02  |  102263    |       X        | <--- beginning of third transfer
+------------------+------------+----------------+
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you clarify your precise criteria? Are you looking for all pairs of consecutive transactions where the first location is X and the second is Y? That would not return the X dated "3.4.2017 10:02", since we don't know where that will go. That would also exclude transfers from Y to X (which does appear to be the intent). Or, due to special knowledge about X, do we need all X transfers and the transfers that follow them?

Comment: Also - Will the `datetime` column be unique in the table? Or, at least, unique for a given `code`?

Comment: yes datetime will be unique for a give code and basically I need to find the first X in the select (since the query will be limited by date between in the future), then the first Y after the X,  then next X after the Y, etc. (ignoring all the Y and Z and possible future locations between).  If the query starts by Y though, then return the first Y then the first X etc.

Comment: The First X in the example will be 5.1.2017 12:54, the first Y will be  2.2.2017 8:42, the next X will be 24.3.2017 13:07, the next Y will be 25.3.2017 14:01 the next X will be 25.3.2017 14:01 etc. until there are no more entires in the table

Comment: Still not 100% clear: Given a sequence X, Z, Y, Z, X, Z, Y - would you return nothing (because nothing goes directly from X to Y or Y to X), or everything but the Zs (because we have X to Y, then Y to X, then X to Y - we just go through Z each time to get there). Similarly, should **X**, Z, **Y**, Z, Y, **X**, Z, **Y**, Z, Y, Z, Y, Z, **X** just return the highlighted entries? (In your sample data, each X is directly followed by a Y; it sounds like that's not part of the requirement; this will confirm that).

Comment: there are currently no limits to which location and from which a code can travel, therefore the second highlighted entry is the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, MySQL isn't a specialty of mine, so there may be a better way of doing this. However, after checking to see how/if MySQL implemented various concepts (like SQL Server's ROW_NUMBER or LEAD functions), this appears to work.

This uses a trick, where the value of a variable is updated with each row, in sequence, and both the old and new values of the variable are included as columns. This lets us pick up the location from the previous row in the current row. (Note that I am not familiar enough with MySQL to know if this is a deliberate feature; in SQL Server, something similar works - but is not documented as a feature, and is generally thought of as something that could stop working with the next version.)

With that trick, we:

- Limit our records to those that have one of the two locations we're interested in;
- add the previous row's location to the current row; and
- select the desired fields from the rows where the previous row's location is different from that of the current row.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE WhenWhatWhere (`when` datetime, `code` int, `location` char(1), CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (`code`,`when`));

INSERT INTO WhenWhatWhere
VALUES ('2017-01-05 12:54', 102263, 'X')
      ,('2017-02-02 8:42', 102263, 'Y')
      ,('2017-03-02 12:04', 102263, 'Z')
      ,('2017-03-06 13:34', 102263, 'Y')
      ,('2017-03-07 7:57', 102263, 'Z')
      ,('2017-03-07 18:37', 102263, 'Y')
      ,('2017-03-09 17:47', 102263, 'Z')
      ,('2017-03-13 7:56', 102263, 'Y')
      ,('2017-03-21 11:44', 102263, 'Z')
      ,('2017-03-22 20:28', 102263, 'Y')
      ,('2017-03-24 13:07', 102263, 'X')
      ,('2017-03-25 14:01', 102263, 'Y')
      ,('2017-03-26 8:14', 102263, 'Z')
      ,('2017-03-27 9:52', 102263, 'Y')
      ,('2017-04-03 10:02', 102263, 'X')
;

SET @rownum = 0;
SET @loc1 = 'X';
SET @loc2 = 'Y';
SET @lastloc = '';

-- 
-- Select only the rows where the location changed from the previous row.
SELECT `when`, `code`, `location`
  FROM ( -- Add the location from the previous row; must be sorted to work
        SELECT `when`, `code`, @lastloc `lastloc`, (@lastloc := `location`) `location`
          FROM ( -- Select just the rows that deal with our two locations
                SELECT `when`, `code`, `location`
                  FROM WhenWhatWhere
                 WHERE `location` = @loc1 OR `location` = @loc2
                  -- add additional restrictions (like date range or specific code) here
               ) loc
         ORDER BY `when`
       ) comploc
 WHERE `lastloc` <> `location`
 ORDER BY `when`
;
```

It worked when I [ran it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1aa0dd/8/4) at sqlfiddle.com.